# Worklight HTTP Adapter vs Ajax request

Tags: ajax, ibm-mobilefirst

What are the advantages of using an HTTP Adapter in Worklight IBM to retrieve data from a Restful API instead of an ajax request? I think that using ajax is faster so why would one use such an adapter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the [documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fdevref%2Fc_overview_of_ibm_worklight_adap.html) and [getting started modules](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#server-side-development).

### Benefits of IBM Worklight adapters

Adapters provide various benefits, as follows:

- **Fast Development:** Adapters are developed in JavaScript and XSL. Developers employ flexible and powerful server-side JavaScript to produce succinct and readable code for integrating with back-end applications and processing data. Developers can also use XSL to transform hierarchical back-end data to JSON.
- **Read-only and Transactional Capabilities:** IBM Worklight adapters support read-only and transactional access modes to back-end systems.
- **Security:** IBM Worklight adapters use flexible authentication facilities to create connections with back-end systems. Adapters offer control over the identity of the user with whom the connection is made. The user can be a system user, or a user on whose behalf the transaction is made.
- **Transparency:** Data retrieved from back-end applications is exposed in a uniform manner, so that application developers can access data uniformly, regardless of its source, format, and protocol.