# IBM Worklight adapter vs normal AJAX request

Tags: ajax, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

can anyone explain the details of IBM Worklight adapter vs   normal AJAx request, using architecture.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why need worklight adapter instead direct ajax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29381996/why-need-worklight-adapter-instead-direct-ajax)

Answer (score 0):

A simple google search would have answered your question instead.

- [Worklight HTTP Adapter vs Ajax request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18371120/worklight-http-adapter-vs-ajax-request)
- [Why need worklight adapter instead direct ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29381996/why-need-worklight-adapter-instead-direct-ajax)